# Oracle .NET C# server publish oci.dll not found

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'oci' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

After successfully testing my C# program that uses oracle (System.Data.OracleClient) on my laptop, I published to my server and there I:

Downloaded dotnet: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

./dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel 7.0 -Runtime aspnetcore

Downloaded Oracle OCI:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/odac-downloads.html

which is a zip file: ODAC122010Xcopy_x64.zip

Unzip and drilled down to the install.bat and then ran:

./install.bat all C:\oracle myhome true

However I received the above execution error.

I copied all the dlls I could find in the oracle installation and copied them to the published folder where my csharp exe is, after reading a related post, but still have the same error.

Any clue as to why this oci error is still occurring? How to resolve. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you mixed 32bit and 64bit, that's not possible. Instead of simple copy, better run `install.bat` also on the server.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Installing Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/InstallODP.html#GUID-1AFEBF7B-3917-4E8F-9384-923EE9F5838B)

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit - I did use install.bat as you can see from my synopsis above

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid TO is using the "Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle" (`System.Data.OracleClient`), not the "Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET)" (`Oracle.DataAccess.Client`). Thus the document you linked, does not apply.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Did you add the folder which contains the .dll to `$PATH` environment variable? Apart from non-matching architecture (i.e. 32 bit vs. 64 bit) and the fact that System.Data.OracleClient does not work with modern Oracle clients, I am not aware of any problems. Maybe try version 12.1, there I know it is a working version.

Comment: I added the published directory and the oracle client install to the $PATH. I downloaded and unzipped the Oracle Client v12 to the published directory (I had been trying the latest (v21 as of Aug-2023), but this did not solve it.